# Spring JDBC ResultSet Extractor get object inside object

Tags: spring, jdbc

So for example we have a Person object:

```
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String sex;
private int age;
private Address address;
```

//Plus setters and getters

Here is my resultset

```
public class PersonResultSet implements ResultSetExtractor<Person>{

@Override
public Person extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    person.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
    person.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
    person.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));
    person.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
    // How do i get the address from the table with the ID

    return person;
}
```

}

How would I obtain the address from the address table corresponding to the address ID in the person table to that person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make a join in your query

```
select p.*, a.*
from person p inner join address a on (p.address_id = a.id)
where ...;
```

and in your extractData method your are going to be able to access address' colums

```
    @Override
public Person extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    person.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
    person.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
    person.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));
    person.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));

    Address address = new Address();
    // Make sets as your are doing with person.
    person.setAddress(address);

    return person;
}
```